# VBA - How to merge 2 columns while copying some data from the original row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to merge 2 columns (Product 1 and Product 2) into a new column. However, I want to keep some data (Customer ID and location) from the original rows and copy them into the new rows. In my actual data, there are multiple "Product" rows which are not all located next to one another. Also, I need to copy  the columns and rows into a brand new merged dataset from columns A-C to columns G to I, rather than just editing the old column to incorporate the new rows.

[image: Example]

```
Sub CopySecondaryProduct()

Range("A:D").Copy Range("G:J")
Range("J:J").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I:I").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial

Range("G:H").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("G:H").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

This is the code I used, but it returned the error that the copy and paste areas aren't the same size. Also, there would be a problem of the headings also copying into the new column. For this code the headings are in the first row because I deleted the "What I have" and "What I need".

Thank you

Comment: Where is the code you have tried and what problems did you have with it?

Comment: I have added it in now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you copy the whole columns. Try this instead. It is not that much robust but it should work in this case:

```
Sub CopySecondaryProduct()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A:C").Copy Range("G:G")
Range("A3:A" & LastRow).Copy Range("G" & LastRow + 1)
Range("B3:B" & LastRow).Copy Range("H" & LastRow + 1)
Range("D3:D" & LastRow).Copy Range("I" & LastRow + 1)

End Sub
```